# Vue.js - Element UI - Form validation regexp

Tags: regex, validation, vuejs2

I'd like to validate a form using `vue-js 2.3` and `element-ui`

Apparently, they use [async-validator](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator) to validate the form.  The documentation is [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form).

#### Example

https://jsfiddle.net/skd3nyqh/

#### Problem

> Uncaught Error: Unknown rule type  D*([2-9]d{2})(D*)([2-9]d{2})(D*)(d{4})D*

I do not know how to validate a field with `regexp`. I find the documentation not explicit enough on that topic.

Comment: When I run your fiddle, I see no such error in my console.

Comment: I just did it again https://jsfiddle.net/skd3nyqh/ :/

Comment: Ok, the error shows now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator#pattern).

> Pattern
>
> The pattern rule property indicates a regular expression that the
>   value must match to pass validation.

Use

```
{required: true, pattern:/\D*([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)([2-9]\d{2})(\D*)(\d{4})\D*/, message: 'Please input phone', trigger: 'blur' }
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skd3nyqh/1/).

Comment: Very sound answer, but is there not any way to implement this pattern globally for whole Element-UI Component?